# Remove phrase from string using regex and a variable

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help me with this regex I can't get the regex to match. I'm trying to remove the phrases that match from the string

```js
let url = 'en-gb/products/product-category/186/product-type/2';
let word = "product-category";
let regex = new RegExp("\/" + word + "\/\d+", "g");
let output = url.replace(regex, '');
//desired output = 'en-gb/products/product-type/2'
console.log(output);
```

Comment: What's wrong with this attempt, specifically?

Comment: You have an extra `/` at the beginning of the regexp, so it's looking for `//product-category`.

Comment: There's also no need to escape `/` when you're creating the regexp with `new RegExp`

Comment: That was a mistake copying that's not the problem. I'm not getting the output like that just the original string

Comment: `category` should be `word`

Comment: also a mistake copying it

Comment: removing the escape \ doesn't change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, you need to do it like so:

```js
let url = 'en-gb/products/product-category/186/product-type/2';
let word = 'product-category';
let regex = new RegExp(word + '/\\d+/', 'g');
let output = url.replace(regex, '');
//desired output = 'en-gb/products/product-type/2'
console.log(output);
```

Also please try to be consistent with either double or single quotes.